# \b is not working. \\ is givin the wrong output. Why putchar() behave differenlty in while scope than in if clause?

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

**1-10. Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each tab by \t, each
backspace by \b, and each backslash by \. This makes tabs and backspaces visible in an
unambiguous way.**

I tried to write it a several times. This is what i came up with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i ;
    while ((i = getchar())!= EOF){
        if (i == '\t'){
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('t');
        }
        if (i == '\b'){
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('b');
        }
        if (i == '\\'){
            //putchar('\\');
            putchar('\\');
        }
        if (i != '\t'){
        putchar(i);
        }
    }
}
```

You must have notice I have commented out teh putchar in third if clause.
I have Three questions.

1. The '\b' character is not working at all. I can't find any possibility to print out a '\b'. How
   to Do it?
2. The putchar in 3rd if clause is printing three times the backward slash. And when commented out,
   it prints 2 times(as desired by the question). Why..?
3. In the 4th if clause, putchar is working fine. But as soon as I  take it out from the if clause
   print it into the While Scope(which was my first try).
   it prints out '\t' plus actual tab space then after the next character??

Why is this happening..? What is the reason..?

```
//if (i != '\t'){    
            putchar(i); -> this is inside the while scope.
            //}
output:
test*tab*this. (executing getchar)
test\t    this (executing putchar)
```

PS - I Cannot use else clause. or anyhting other than mentioned above. I haven't reached till else or continue in the book.Thus, I have purposely avoided the use of else.

Comment: You should add some `else` to your code. Otherwise the last `if (i != '\t')` will also print `'\b'`, `'\'` or other characters that are checked above.

Comment: Either use `else` as @Gerhardh suggested, or `continue` from inside the `if`s.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thank you for replying. I have already tried using else or continue as you mentioned. I went through every possible answers already present on Stackoverflow regarding this questions. But non of it is helping. I still can't print \b in the output. Also, yes it is working when i modify it. But still, I can't figure out why did it worked...?

Comment: The three questions I have asked is to understand the root cause. It IS working in a way or other, but why,,? I don't want to say "god knows why it worked." Please help me out here.

Comment: You can't easily *input* a `\b`. How are you doing that?

Comment: @pmg i don't know how to. I'm just pressing the backspace key on keyboard. Sorry if I'm being silly.

Comment: The backspace from the keyboard never reaches your program. Your Operating System deals with it. You can use a file with embedded backspaces or pipe the output of some other program into your executable.

Comment: regaarding: `main()`  There are only two valid signatures for `main()`.  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   Notice they all have a return type of `int`.  In the early days of C, a `int` was assumed when ever a specific type was needed.  In modern C, omitting the 'type' is considered an error

Answer (score 1):

No `else` or `continue`, using a helper variable

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    while ((i = getchar()) != EOF) {
        int processed = 0;
        if (i == '\t') {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('t');
            processed = 1;
        }
        if (i == '\b') {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('b');
            processed = 1;
        }
        if (i == '\\') {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('\\');
            processed = 1;
        }
        if (!processed) putchar(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
$ echo -e 'backslash [\\]\ntab [\t]\nback [\b]'
backslash [\]
tab [   ]
back ]

$ echo -e 'backslash [\\]\ntab [\t]\nback [\b]' | ./a.out
backslash [\\]
tab [\t]
back [\b]
```